# Verificación de varios registros Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Buen día tengo una colección con 5 mil registros, pero antes de insertarlos en BD debo verificar que en la misma BD no exista ese registro, y si existe devolver un mensaje de error.
La collección es la siguiente, por ejemplo debo validar que la tenencia no exista en BD, eso quiere decir que debo validarlo elemento por elemento, pero cuando lo hago por 5 mil registros esto demora aproximadamente 2 horas, y para mi esto es súper ineficiente, no se si exista una forma óptima que no sea la que ya les comenté.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#874
  #items: array:5 [
    0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#878
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 1
        "tenencia" => "2235050"
        "clase" => 58
        "marca" => 153
      ]
    }
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#876
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 2
        "tenencia" => "2235051"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => 153
      ]
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#858
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 3
        "tenencia" => "2235052"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => 153
      ]
    }
    3 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#856
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 4
        "tenencia" => "2235053"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => 153        
      ]
    }
    4 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#850
      #items: array:12 [
        "no" => 5
        "tenencia" => "2235054"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => "200"            
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

La forma que utilizo para verificar que exista es:

```
foreach ($filas as $k => $v)}
{
   $verifica = $entidad->where($campoBD, $v['tenencia'])->count();
   if (!$verifica) 
   {
      #ya esta ingresado en DB
   }
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta cómo llevas a cabo ese proceso

Comment: cual es el campo que no debe repetirse? al crear la base de datos puedes poner esta campo como `unique` o crear un `triger before` !

Comment: Eso podría ser una buena opción

Comment: Me parecería basada en opiniones la pregunta puesto que habría mas de una forma de abordarlo, sin embargo y asumiendo que uses *MySQL* te recomiendo mucho leas sobre optimización de [sentencias `INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html)

Comment: Hola @BetaM fijate que estoy usando PostgreSQL

Comment: la línea de acción sería la misma, es decir no debes concentrar todo el esfuerzo únicamente en tu lenguaje/framework de uso, sino que debes ampliar y analizar sobre optimización al postgresql donde tienes esto funionando, este enlace te puede servir de guía: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49646/bulk-insert-buffer-size-and-innodb